# Find the average temperature between $t=0$ and $t=24$ when $T(t) = 49+8t-(1/2)t^2$ degrees.

Tags: calculus

What was the average temperature during that period?

My initial thought was to take the derivative of the problem, plug in 24 for $t$ and solve.  I was wrong.  This is what I have

$T'=8-t=8-24=-16$ deg.

Should I have taken the integral instead of the derivative?

Answer (score 2):

The average value of $f(t)$ over the interval $[a,b]$ is 
$$\frac{\int_a^b f(t)\,dt}{b-a}.$$
To see that derivative has not much to do with average value, suppose that $f(t)$ is the constant $K$ over our interval. Then the average value must be $K$. But $f'(t)=0$ for all $t$.

Comment: ok so the integral of 49+8t-(1/2)t^2 = 49x+4x^2-0.166667x^3+c.  If I take this equation and plug in 24 for the value I get approx 1176. I will multiply that by 1/(b-a) or 1/24 and get an answer of 49 deg which is correct.  thank you for your help

Comment: One integral is $49t+4t^2-\frac{t^3}{6}$. Plug in $24$, take away the (easy) result of plugging in $0$, then divide by $24$. We get $49+4(24)-\frac{24^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative gives the rate of change of temperature. Instead, you should compute the integral from 0 to 24 hours and then divide by 24 to get the average temperature.